# How to make abstract static properties

Tags: c#, static, abstract

I know this can be done for methods by using an interface. But interfaces cannot have fields or static properties (which would not help because it would specify one value for all classes that implement the interface). I could also have default values for the properties at the abstract class. But ideally I'd like to force every inheriting class to implement values for these properties. Values which can then still be used in abstract methods on the abstract class level.

The benefits of each property:
- Abstract; The base class requires this property to be implemented but doesn't specify a value.
- Static; only store one value per type of implementation, instead of per object.

```
public interface IPiece
{
    readonly int Points;
    readonly char Letter;
}

public abstract class Piece
{
    public static readonly int Points;
    public static readonly char Letter;
}

public class King : Piece, IPiece
{
    public int Points = 0;
    public int Letter = 'K';
}
```

Comment: Interfaces can have properties though?  I am not understanding what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @maccettura I get the error "interfaces cannot contain fields". Either way, that would be per created object and I'd like to specify these properties per type of implementation. So what you have with a static property.

Comment: FYI those are not properties, those are fields.  A property has a `get` and `set` associated with it.

Comment: @MrFox Make your interface contain two _properties_ that are _read only_ (i.e only expose a `get`).  Then your implementing classes can dictate their own implementation data for this.  If your abstract class above _only_ contains Points and Letter its prolly not necessary to have since the classes that implement the interface have to have the two properties implemented anyway.  Only use the abstract class when there is some sort of _shared_ functionality/data

Comment: `How to make abstract static properties` You can't.

Comment: I can only warn you not to missuse static and abstract. Making any value static to share it between instance is terible idea. We lost count how often people thought it "was the easiest way", only to end up realizing (or forcing their replacement to realize) just what a terrible idea that was. And then having to undo it. Put whatever you want to share into a struct or small class. Have the instance the instance be automatically created if not given in cosntructor. Usually give in in the constructor. That way at least you have a option to have multiple values.

Comment: There is actually a cautioary tale in the .NET Framework itself, the Application Settings manager: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings It is realized entirely via static function calls and properties. And few things are quite as annoying as having to refractor your entire code to replace it, because you suddenly need 2 setting contexts. And that case **will** happen.

Comment: @Christopher If it is set in the constructor (as you seem to be suggesting) then it will be stored per instance - which seems to be one of the things the OP is trying to avoid. _I am not defending what the OP is asking for, just explaining it._

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for the advice, but I'm actually looking to implement a chess game, so I don't have to worry about different point systems for the pieces. Calculating more precise points for a board situation is done elsewhere. I'm trying to reduce memory usage, although it's probably irrelevant in relation to the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a static abstract property. Static members of the class are not subject to polymorphism. If you wish to have a property defined in abstract class which should be shared by all implementations and you **don't know it in compile-time**, you can create a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) type for it, or a wrapper around if its not type defined in your code. Then you can have something like this:

```
public abstract class Piece // or interface
{
    public SingletonIntWrapper Points { get; }
    public SingletonCharWrapper Letter { get; }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `public SingletonIntWrapper Points { get; }` vs `public int Points { get; }`

Comment: All instances of the derived class will share the value and it's not hardcoded in the class. How you assign that value is a different story.

Comment: @nemanja I like the idea of a singleton but still assigning the Points or Letter uses a backingfield for each instance of `Piece`. You should use a static backingfield.

Comment: @Wouter It depends on the the particular use-case, now that we have more details on the problem from the comments, I'd say that static readonly backing field would also be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

The standard pattern for solving this is:

```
public interface IPiece
{
    int Points { get; }
    char Letter { get; }
}

public class King : IPiece
{
    public int Points => 0;
    public char Letter => 'K';
}
```

There is no need to use `static` at all, since `0` and `K` are literals, and thus (like `static`) are effectively stored only once per class.

*Note also that I have removed your `abstract class` - it is not useful as is since there is no logic in it. An `abstract class` without logic is conceptually equivalent to an `interface` (which you already have) so is unnecessary at this stage.*

If you really want to use a `static` then you could use:

```
public class King : IPiece
{
    private static int points = 0;
    private static char letter = 'K';

    public int Points => points;
    public char Letter => letter;
}
```

but there is no major benefit to that.

Answer (score 1):

First, interfaces can have properties, but they can't have fields (as indicated in the comments on the question).

```
public interface IPiece
{
    int Points {get;} // readonly properties in interfaces must be defined like this
    char Letter {get;}
}
```

You also need to have your abstract class inherit from the interface in order for it to have access to the properties defined within it. Because it is an abstract class, you must mark the properties as abstract

```
public abstract class Piece : IPiece
{
    public abstract int Points {get;}
    public abstract char Letter {get;}
}
```

From there, you can create an implementation (King) of your abstract class (Piece). Since this is not an abstract implementation, you must provide implementations of the properties at this time.

```
public class King : Piece
{
    public override int Points {get; private set;} = 0;
    public override char Letter {get; private set;} = 'K';
}
```

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties) for further examples on property inheritance.

Comment: I'll be more explicit. :) The OP wants `only store one value per type of implementation, instead of per object.`. `= 0` won't do that. It will create a backing field for each instance of the object (which appears to be the thing the OP is trying to avoid).

Comment: You are correct. If you are never going to have instances configured at runtime, there would be no practical difference between the two. There might be minor performance optimizations the compiler could do, but I'm not well versed in how the compiler parses those kinds of things.

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker I suppose "private set;" could be avoided for C# 6 and later? Or was it made specifically to show that it will not be possible to chane the value?

Comment: Oh yeah, that is optional now... isn't it... old habits and all that...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `const` or `static readonly` backingfield. (There are differences). Also the abstract class and the interface are redundant. Either let all your pieces derive from Piece or let them implement IPiece.

```
public interface IPiece
{
    int Points { get; }
    char Letter { get; }
}

public abstract class Piece : IPiece
{
    public abstract int Points { get; }
    public abstract char Letter { get; }
}

public class King : Piece
{
    public const int POINTS = 0;
    public const char LETTER = 'K';

    public override int Points { get { return POINTS; } }
    public override char Letter { get { return LETTER; } }
}
```

Note:
Now still you cannot use the public `const` or `static readonly` in a very usefull way. Because you cannot reach the definition of the value without an instance. For example you cannot get the value of the King.LETTER when enumerating all values to determine what `Piece` to construct based on a character.